# How to correct this delete query

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, date

I need to do a select query like this:

```
select *
from faults
where insertdate < DATEADD(DAY, -30, sessiondate)
```

The query should be correct but I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Since, sessiondate contains a date but as string and not in date format.

Is there a way to do this query with a string instead of a date type?

Comment: Either the insertdate or sessiondate is invalid in one or more records.

Comment: i put select instead of delete for testing but the purpose is the same , to get all data from a certain date and subtract that date to 30 days

Comment: you have to type cast your sessiondate column to date data type, without that your query will not work correctly

Answer (score 1):

The error seems pretty clear.   `insertdate` and/or `sessiondate` are stored as strings.  You should fix the data.

SQL Server has three ways to convert such values:

- Implicitly by putting the strings in a place where date/times are expected.
- Explicitly using `CAST()`/`CONVERT()`.
- Explicitly and flexibly using `PARSE()`.

You need to figure out what your format is.  They you can convert it.  You've provided no information, but a typical method would be:

```
where insertdate < DATEADD(DAY, -30, TRY_CONVERT(date, sessiondate, <date style here>))
```

Usually the formats available with `CONVERT()` are sufficient (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)).  Sometimes, you may need to use `TRY_PARSE()`.

EDIT:

To support timestamps, then you need to convert to `datetime2`:

```
try_convert(datetime2, '2019-07-08T09:17:19+02:00')
```

You should be comparison to a value with a timestamp.

Comment: if the dates are like this 2019-07-08T09:17:19+02:00 what kind of data style should i put?  plus i have other extra date 2019-07-08T09:17:19Z like this one inside the table

Comment: @fusolage What should you do? Start over. Change your schema to use the correct datatypes, then change your application to populate them correctly. Once that is done, you NEVER have this problem again. Consider carefully if you need to store values that correspond to different timezones - if so, you should consider storing all times as UTC.